# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy to M/d/yyyy

Tags: c#

```
string sysFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToDateTime("29/05/2018").ToString(sysFormat), 
                    sysFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I had use this but not able to convert in M/d/yyyy format.

Comment: Have you explored the custom date format characters?

Comment: And what is the value of _sysFormat_?

Comment: @Steve first line of code

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
var dateTime =  DateTime.ParseExact("29/05/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var formattedDateTime = dateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M\\/d\\/yyyy");
```

Result: `2/7/2019`